OpenSearch 1.3 k-NN search with filtering on nested fields
In OpenSearch 2.13, this is supported: https://opensearch.org/docs/2.13/search-plugins/knn/nested-search-knn/#k-nn-search-with-filtering-on-nested-fields
If I try this same query in OpenSearch 1.3, I get an error saying that filter isn't allowed:
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[knn] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [filter]",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 200
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[knn] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [filter]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 200
    },
    "status": 400
}

Is there a way to have documents with multiple vectors and do k-NN search with a filter in OpenSearch 1.3? I tried embedding the data I need to filter on into the nested field (i.e. a copy of the whole record alongside each vector) but couldn't quite figure out how to get a query to work on that either.

This feature was implemented in v2.9, and it is not backported to older versions. You can filter the documents with KNN queries via either pre filter or post filter. But it comes with some limitations explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-operations.html#version_opensearch_2.11
